# A question about the solutions of a diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I would like to know if it's possible to find the solution of the following equation:
$$x^k+y^h=z^{kh}$$
in which:
$$\{x,y,z\}\subset\mathbb{N}$$
given $k$ and $h$ with:
$$\{k,h\}\subset\mathbb{N}$$

Comment: What is $m$? Did you mean $h$?  Also, notationally, we write $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$ (preferred) or $\{x,y,z\}\subset \mathbb N$. $\{x,y,z\}\in \mathbb N$ is abuse of notation.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Sorry. I have just corrected it

Comment: For some $h$ and $k$ certainly. One can cheat and make one of $h$ or $k$ equal to $1$. Or let $h=k=2$, $5^4$ can be expressed as the sum of two non-zero squares. It cannot *always* be done, let $h=k\gt 2$, that would violate Fermat's Last Theorem.